# How to write a function to return original dataframes with selected column values and with difference between common column as a third dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

`df1`:

```py
          date      score   perf    
0       2021-08-01  2       4
1       2021-08-02  4       5
2       2021-08-03  6       7
```

`df2`:

```py
          date      score   perf
0       2021-08-01  2       7
1       2021-08-02  4       8
2       2021-08-03  6       7
```

I want to return `df1`, `df2`, and a variation in perf of `df1` and `df2` as a third dataframe together as shown in this picture:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/14627505).

Comment: Why are you skipping the middle row in the output? (2021-08-02)

Comment: I am interested in only getting rows based on column values condition, in this case, score = [2,6] i.e, I should be able to pass score = [2,6] as a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 0):

The illustration of tables you shared does not match with the values of `df1`and `df2`.
But anyway, you can use [**`pandas.merge`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) to bring the column(s) you need to do the substraction.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['01/08/2021', '02/08/2021', '03/08/2021'],
                    'score' : [2, 4, 6],
                    'perf': [4, 5, 7]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['01/08/2021', '02/08/2021', '03/08/2021'],
                    'score' : [2, 4, 6],
                    'perf': [7, 8, 7]})

out = df1.merge(df2[['date','perf']], on='date', how='left')
out['perf'] = out['perf_x'] - out['perf_y']
out = out.drop(['perf_x','perf_y'], axis=1)
```

##### `>>> print(out)`

[image]

> **Note**: In case you want to substract all the columns of both dataframes, you can use [**`pandas.DataFrame.sub`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) instead to substract one dataframe from another.

##### Edit :

Now, if you want to display the three dataframes in a Excel sheet (as shown in your illustation), you can use this function:

```
list_df = [df1, df2, df3]
df1.name = 'Table 1'
df2.name = 'Table 2'
df3.name = 'Table 3 (tabl1perf - tabl2perf)'

def display_results(dfs):
    sr = 1
    with pd.ExcelWriter('your_excel_name.xlsx') as writer:
        for df in dfs:
            df.to_excel(writer, startrow=sr, index=False)
            workbook  = writer.book
            worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
            title = df.name
            worksheet.write(sr-1, 0, title)
            sr += (df.shape[0] + 3)

display_results(list_df)
```

##### `>>> Output (in Excel)`

[image]

Comment: I think the OP needs both the df1 and df2 to be printed above the resulted dataframe as well

Comment: Yes, a function that returns df1 and df2 and df3 (perf column of df1 - perf column of df2) with headers as shown in the resulting dataframe

Comment: If you mean by _"that returns df1 and df2 and df3"_ displaying them in a Excel file, take a look at the EDIT I added in my answer.

Comment: No really, I would like to return as a data frame. I have a function that returns the data frame but I could not display it as I wanted like in the picture in the post. Note: score = [2,6]. This is the parameter of function I can pass to give only those rows.

Comment: This code does not display the table as I want 
merge_df = pd.concat(
        [
            df.loc[index,col_list]
            for df in [df1, df2, variation_df]
        ],
        keys=title+["Variation"],
        axis=0
    )
    #display(merge_df)
    if save is not None:
        merge_df.to_excel(save)
    return merge_df